# How can I skip the else if statement?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have a condition like this:

```
IF Exists(INSERT)

ELSE IF EXISTS(INSERT)

ELSE
```

I want to skip execution of 'else if' when 'IF' is already executed.OR Is there any way to skip both IF and ELSE IF if the value doest not exist. I don't want to execute them both. Any suggestion?

Comment: `ELSE IF` already will be skipped if the `IF` condition fires.

Comment: *skip execution of 'else if'* Do you mean the check conditions ? Or the statements inside the `Else IF` condition. If condition is not satisfied then the statement inside the if condition will not be executed

Comment: The main purpose and the functionality of `ELSE IF` is to skip the next blocks if one block executed

Comment: Skip Check Condition not the block. Obviously, It won't execute the block.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void yourMethod() {
    int a;
    int b = 3;
    int c = 45;
    boolean test1 = true;

    if (test1 == true) {
        //Then here you can put your code
        //Example
        a = b*c;

    } else {
        //Here goes your secondary code, if you dont want do something in
        //here just leve it blank
        //or better dont include a else statement at all
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.... sorry, my english is sometimes not good enough. The code was written on my cellphone.

Answer (score 0):

ELSE IF will skipped if IF-Condition executes.

Answer (score 0):

you can research MERGE INTO

[MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment *Skip Check Condition not the block. Obviously, It won't execute the block*. This is how `ELSE IF` works

```
IF Exists(INSERT) -- check and satisfied

ELSE IF EXISTS(INSERT) --skipped 

ELSE -- skipped
```

---

```
IF Exists(INSERT) -- check and Not satisfied

ELSE IF EXISTS(INSERT) --check and satisfied 

ELSE -- skipped
```

---

```
IF Exists(INSERT) -- check and Not satisfied

ELSE IF EXISTS(INSERT) --check and Not satisfied

ELSE -- checked
```

Instead of `ELSE IF` if you have only `IF` then even though the previous `IF` is satisfied all the IF statements will be checked